# Cython parallel loop prange too slow

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing, cython

I am trying to grasp how to make Cython run parallel loops. Code below does run at about same speed and system monitor shows only one core load at any point in time. Wham I am doing wrong?

I am using Ipython Notebook to run it.

```
from cython.parallel import prange, parallel, threadid

cdef long i,j
cdef long total,subtotal = 0
cdef long n = 10**10

for i in range(n):
    total += i

CPU times: user 9.02 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 9.02 s
Wall time: 9.03 s

with nogil, parallel():
    for i in prange(8):
        subtotal = 0
        for j in range(i,n,8):
            subtotal += i
        total += subtotal

CPU times: user 13.1 s, sys: 28 ms, total: 13.1 s
Wall time: 13.4 s
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect here? You are not really doing any calculation in each loop. In fact I am a little surprised that the second one is a little faster than the first one.

Comment: I need to make an example how parallel loops can achieve 4X speed over single threaded loop. I provided a new example.

Comment: Are you compiling with `openmp` in `extra_compile_args`?

Comment: I have no idea what that even is. I am using Ipython Notebook. I use `%load_ext cythonmagic` and then `%%cython` to run the code above.

Comment: Instead of %%cython try using %%cython -c -fopenmp

Comment: Sorry, should only be: %%cython -c fopenmp